# MONTH NUMBER (MONTH BETWEEN 1AND 12),

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a table in Access using SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE STATS
(ID NUMBER  REFERENCES STATION(ID),
MONTH NUMBER (MONTH BETWEEN 1AND 12),
TEMP_F NUMBER (TEMP_F BETWEEN -80 AND 150),
RAIN_I NUMBER (RAIN_I BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
PRIMARY KEY (ID, MONTH));
```

Everytime I run the query it gives me '`Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement`'. I tried some troubleshooting but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you can use BETWEEN like that? (I don't actually know for the record). If you can, then the missing space between `"1AND"` is likely to be an issue

Comment: Use the query design window to create the sql. You seem to be either missing a lot of commas or square brackets or you do not understand functions.

Comment: Thanks. No space is not the issue. Although thanks for rectifying the error. I put the space but no luck

Answer (score 2):

This statement creates a table with 3 fields:

```sql
CREATE TABLE STATS (
    ID LONG REFERENCES STATION(ID),
    [MONTH] SHORT,
    TEMP_F DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID, [MONTH]),
    CONSTRAINT valid_month CHECK ([MONTH] BETWEEN 1 AND 12),
    CONSTRAINT valid_TEMP_F CHECK (TEMP_F BETWEEN -80 AND 150)
    );
```

Notes:

1. The `ID` field in my `STATION` table is AutoNumber datatype, so I chose long integer for the datatype of `STATS.ID`.
2. `MONTH` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  I enclosed that name in square brackets so Access will not mistake it for the `Month()` function.  But it would be better to choose a field name which is not a reserved word.
3. I used `CHECK` constraints to limit the values `[MONTH]` and `TEMP_F` will accept.  But that means **the statement must be executed from ADO** because Access DDL statements executed from DAO can not support `CHECK` constraints.  (Note a query run from the query designer uses DAO.)  I used a string variable to hold the statement and then executed it from `CurrentProject.Connection` (which is an ADO object) like this ...

```vb
Dim strCreate As String
strCreate = "CREATE TABLE STATS (" & vbCrLf & _
    "ID LONG REFERENCES STATION(ID)," & vbCrLf & _
    "[MONTH] SHORT," & vbCrLf & _
    "TEMP_F DOUBLE," & vbCrLf & _
    "CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID, [MONTH])," & vbCrLf & _
    "CONSTRAINT valid_month CHECK ([MONTH] BETWEEN 1 AND 12)," & vbCrLf & _
    "CONSTRAINT valid_TEMP_F CHECK (TEMP_F BETWEEN -80 AND 150)" & vbCrLf & _
    ");"
Debug.Print strCreate
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strCreate
```

You can extend this example by including your `RAIN_I` field, and adding a `CHECK` constraint for it.

Comment: I enclosed MONTH in square brackets:                               CREATE TABLE STATS(
ID LONG  REFERENCES STATION(ID),
[MONTH] SHORT ([MONTH] BETWEEN 1 AND 12),
TEMP_F DECIMAL (TEMP_F BETWEEN -80 AND 150),
RAIN_I DECIMAL (RAIN_I BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
PRIMARY KEY (ID, [MONTH])); Still get the same error. Can't I do without using the CONSTRAINT key.

Comment: even CREATE TABLE STATS (
    ID LONG REFERENCES STATION(ID),
    [MONTH] SHORT,  
    CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID, [MONTH]),
    CONSTRAINT valid_month CHECK ([MONTH] BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
    TEMP_F NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT valid_temp_f CHECK (TEMP_F BETWEEN -80 AND 150)
    RAIN_I NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT valid_rain_i CHECK (RAIN_I BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
    ); does not work. Syntax error in constraint clause.

Comment: That statement didn't have a comma before `TEMP_F NUMBER`.  Also I suggest you define all the fields before you add `CONSTRAINT` clauses ... following the pattern in my answer.  I updated the answer to include another field and constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table STATS (
    ID number,
    MONTH number,
    TEMP_F number,
   RAIN_I number,
    constraint valid_MONTH check (MONTH between 1 and 12),
    constraint valid_TEMP_F check (TEMP_F between -80 and 150),
    constraint valid_RAIN_I check (RAIN_I between 1 and 100)
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.